# Mapstruct @Mapping(expression="...") in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, mapstruct

Is it possible to express a Kotlin expression in the `@Mapping` annotation?

The (simplified) problem is the following:

I have this data class:

```
data class Data (
    val myClass: MyClass
)
```

and:

```
data class DataDto (
    myString: String
)

fun String.toMyClass() = ...
```

Currently I would like to do something like that:

```
@Mapper
interface RefDataMapper {

    @Mapping(expression = "kotlin(myString?.toMyClass())", target = "myClass")
    fun toDomain(dataDto: DataDto) : Data

}
```

Currently it seems that expressions can written only in Java so the above solution doesn't work. It is possible to do what I'm trying to do?

N.B. I cannot use the decorator because in the `Data` class this property is set as `val` so, I can set this property only during instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

MapStruct does not have Kotlin expression support because MapStruct is only capable of generating Java code currently. Therefore, even if you mappers are defined in Kotlin the mapper implementation will be written in Java.

You will have to adapt your expression to use the `java(...)` format.

Comment: Yes, this seems the only solution. I suppose that is not convenient use mapstruct in Kotlin projects. For more complicated expression I will use the features provided by Kotlin in terms of conciseness, etc...

Comment: Well you can always use custom methods and qualifiers to perform custom mappings. There is no need to use expression always

Comment: can you be clearer? I mean as I wrote in my thread i cannot customize the mapping using a decorator because the field in my example cannot be modified after creation. So I have to initialize during the creation of the instance. That's why I thought about expression. But I you have an alternative I will check your answer. My goal is to apply the method toMyClass to the field in the DTO to fill the field in the domain object.

Comment: Writing a custom mapping method is not using a decorator. It is the same as using an expression, but it is written properly. Check https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#invoking-custom-mapping-method